# Objective-C releases C++ Object when passed to Swift. How do I prevent this?

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift

I have a C++ library that I need to integrate into Swift.  I thought it was working until I realized that the C++ object inside my Objective-C wrapper was being released.

## C++ layer

MyCPPClass.hpp

```
class MyCPPClass {
    std:string myString;
    int myInt;
}
```

MyCPPProcessor.hpp

```
class MyCPPProcessor {
    public:
        static MyCPPClass getMeACPPClass();
}
```

MyCPPProcessor.cpp

```
MyCPPClass MyCPPProcessor::getMeACPPClass() {
   CPPClass myCPP;
   myCPP.myString = "This is my String";
   myInt = 23;  
   return myCPP;
}
```

## Objective-C layer

CPPClassWrapper.h

```
@interface CPPClassWrapper : NSObject
@end
```

CPPClassWrapper.mm

```
@interface CPPClassWrapper()
    @property MyCPPClass *myCPPClass;
@end

@implementation CPPClassWrapper

    -(instancetype) initWithMyCPPClass:(MyCPPClass *)myCPPClass
    {
        self.myCPPClass = myCPPClass;
        return self;
    }
@end
```

MyProcessorWrapper.h

```
@interface MyProcessorWrapper : NSObject
    +(MyClassWrapper *) getMeACPPClass;
@end
```

MyProcessWrapper.mm

```
@implementation MyProcessWrapper

    +(MyCPPCLassWrapper *) getMeACPPClass
    {
        MyCPPClass myCPPClass = MyCPPProcessor::getMeACPPClass()
        CPPClassWrapper *cppClassWrapper = [[CPPClassWrapper alloc] initWithMyCPPCLass: & myCPPClass];
(1)     return cppClassWrapper;
}
@end
```

By the time we've reached line (1), all is as expected.  The cppClassWrapper has a pointer to myCPPClass and it can be inspected and verified.

But then, when it is passed to the Swift layer cppClassWrapper.myCPPClass is released and its destructor is called.

## Swift Layer

```
class MyCPPProcessorBridge: MyCPPProcessorWrapper
{
    public static func getMeACPPClass -> MyCPPClassBridge
    {
        let myCPPWrapper:MyCPPClassWrapper = super.getMeACPPClass()
(2)        return MyCPPClassBridge(wrapper: myCPPWrapper)
    }
}
```

When we reach line (2) myCPPWrapper has lost it's pointer to myCPPClass because it has been released.

How do I prevent this release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with passing your object to Swift.

The problem is in your `+getMeACPPClass` method. The variable `myCPPClass` has automatic storage. It lives on the stack. When that method returns, its stack space goes invalid and that object is destroyed. Your Objective-C `CPPClassWrapper` class only holds a pointer to that same storage. That pointer is left dangling after the C++ object is destroyed.

So, your point (1) is the *last* point when that variable was valid. As soon as control returns to the caller of that method, it's invalid.

You need to either: 1) allocate the object on the heap and use `std::shared_ptr` to manage it, both in `+getMeACPPClass` and `CPPClassWrapper`; or 2) have `CPPClassWrapper` hold an object, not just a pointer, and it will have a **copy** of the object that was originally created in `+getMeACPPClass`.